# Channel Writer requiring Task.Delay and not processing all messages

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, task, system.threading.channels

I am adding messages to a threading channel and reading from this channel constantly. I noticed that if I do not add a `Task.Delay` then all of the messages are not processed. The program will exit with maybe 10 messages processed when it should be 1000.

Adding a `Task.Delay` after each write seems hacky. Is there a better way to read all messages in the channel without adding a `Task.Delay` after each write?

Is there something wrong with my `StartListener()` method?

```
internal class Program
{
    static List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    private static Channel<string> messageList = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
    static int midpointCount = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(() => StartListener()));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int task = i;
            taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => StartJob(task)));
        }            
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Total Messages Processed: {0} in time {1} MessageListCount {2}", midpointCount, sw.Elapsed, messageList.Reader.Count);
    }

    private static async Task<string> StartListener()
    {
        var cancellationtoken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)).Token;
        await foreach (var msg in messageList.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cancellationtoken))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref midpointCount);
            }
        }           
        return "Finished";
    }

    private static async Task<string> StartJob(int TaskNum)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var cancellationtoken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)).Token;
            try
            {                    
                var message = string.Format("TaskNum {0} Message added #{1}", TaskNum, rnd.Next(1, 3000));
                await messageList.Writer.WriteAsync(message);
                await Task.Delay(50);  //<--- Here it seems it will only read all messages with a delay involved.
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // ignored
            }
        }           
        return "Finished";
    }
}
```

Comment: you are ignoring the Operation cancelation. You would probably see what is happening if you didnt do that. I can imagine it complains about not beeing able to WriteAsync for watever reason

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(() => StartListener()));
> ```

`StartListener` returns a `Task`. You wrap that in `Task.Run`, starting another thread to run that task. You then pass than task to [the `Task.WhenAll` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall), which **returns a `Task`** that you promptly throw away.

The only tasks you add to the `taskList` variable are the `StartJob` tasks. Your `Main` method will finish as soon as all of the `StartJob` tasks have finished. It will not wait for the `StartListener` task to finish.

Change your code to wait for the listener to finish.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    
    taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => StartListener()));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int task = i;
        taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => StartJob(task)));
    }

     Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
     sw.Stop();
     
     Console.WriteLine("Total Messages Processed: {0} in time {1} MessageListCount {2}", 
        midpointCount, sw.Elapsed, messageList.Reader.Count);
}
```

Comment: ahhh. How did I miss this? I need some coffee. Thanks Richard